# How to exit from a listener in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've Googled a lot but I still didn't find any solution for my problem. I'm new to Android so sorry for a stupid question.
Here is my code:

```
final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), ShowActivity.class);
webView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeListener(this)
{
    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft()
    {
        articleID--;
        //System.out.println("SWIPE_LEFT");
        myIntent.putExtra("id", articleID);
        System.out.println(myIntent.toString());
        Swiped = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight()
    {
        articleID++;
        //System.out.println("SWIPE_RIGHT");
        myIntent.putExtra("id", articleID);
        System.out.println(myIntent.toString());
        Swiped = true;
    }
});
if (Swiped == true)
    mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

So, the question is: why my new activity doesn't start? I mean it doesn't even get into if-condition. Seems like that because of listener it ignores any code below, doesn't it? How to exit from listener? Btw, i'm trying to start new activity on Swipe. Maybe I need to rework architecture? But i really don't want to =(

This is my SwipeListener class:

```
public class SwipeListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
// Gesture Detector which has onTouchEvent action
// Gesture detector requires custom gesture listener (Which declared below)
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
// Basic Construction
public SwipeListener(Context c) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureListener());
}
// onTouch action. Returns ANY (click and release) event thanks to onTouchEvent of gestureDetector
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

// GestureListener for GestureDetector declaration.
private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 100; // Swipe minimal distance
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY = 100; // swipe minimal speed

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    // Determines the fling velocity and then fires the appropriate swipe event accordingly
    // onFling MUST return false so don't touch it.
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY(); // Y(vertical) Difference between release and press coordinates
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX(); // X(horizontal) Difference between release and press coordinates
            // Determine if swipe was in horizontal or in vertical align
            // Horizontal (left-right)
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                // Check if speed and distance are big enough
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            // Vertical (up-down)
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeDown();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeUp();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("YOU SHALL NOT SWIPE");
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
    // U need to override this
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
    // and this
}

public void onSwipeUp() {
    // and this one too
}

public void onSwipeDown() {
    // U know what to do
}
```

}

Here is a log:

```
01-09 19:21:36.564    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getFlags()' on a null object reference
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1231)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1219)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.weel.ur.ShowActivity.startAct(ShowActivity.java:755)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.weel.ur.ShowActivity$2.onSwipeLeft(ShowActivity.java:347)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.weel.ur.calligraphy.SwipeListener$GestureListener.onFling(SwipeListener.java:51)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:610)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.weel.ur.calligraphy.SwipeListener.onTouch(SwipeListener.java:22)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8382)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2424)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
01-09 19:21:36.565    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-09 19:21:36.566    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-09 19:21:36.567    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-09 19:21:36.567    7758-7758/com.weel.ur W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: I don't think you need the boolean `Swiped` and can just put `mContext.startActivity(myIntent);` into the `onSwipeRight/Left` methods.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. I tried this and i got an exception from SwipeListener class. Do you need the code of that class?

Comment: It might help to have more of the current code for more context.

Comment: its because whole code is messed up. Putting it in my answer.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i've tried and it didn't work=/ Still got an exception for SwipeListener class=/

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i've done it. Don't think that u're gonna need whole log. It says that there are a NullObjectReference somewhere

Comment: DO NOT EVER USE `getBaseContext()`! I'm gonna take a wild guess and say that `ShowActivity.this` is what you need.

Comment: @EugenPechanec changed as you told me. Didn't affect anything=( Still got this "NullPointerObject" thing in android.content.Intent.getFlags()

Comment: As far as I can tell you passed a null `Intent` to `ShowActivity.startAct(Intent)`. Check from where you call this method and verify the code flow.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 using breakpoints i've managed to get this from Android Studio: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Oh... you need to change your code flow. Sorry to say. But the problem you had initially is fixed. This is new issue due to that fix.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 ooohh...=( But how?=/ It's an almost fully working app with tonnes of code and activities.

Comment: Not that big change. Its my lunch time. I can help you after 30 mins.

Comment: Please see the work around in my edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have set default value for `Swiped` to false. Because you are starting activity outside of the listener its is called even before you get a chance to touch the screen. When `onTouchListener` is called value of `Swiped` is changed but you are not starting the activity.

```
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeListener(this)
    {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft()
        {
            articleID--;
            //System.out.println("SWIPE_LEFT");
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ShowActivity.this, ShowActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("id", articleID);
            System.out.println(myIntent.toString());
            ShowActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight()
        {
            articleID++;
            //System.out.println("SWIPE_RIGHT");
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ShowActivity.this, ShowActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("id", articleID);
            System.out.println(myIntent.toString());
            Swiped = true;
            ShowActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Also, you might want to add a condition before `articleID--` and `articleID++`. This will help you when you reach to first and last article in the queue. If so `Swiped` should be set to false or you can reset the `articleID`

Comment: I did as u suggested, but i still got and exception from SwipeListener class, which says: "You shall not swipe"=/

Comment: That a different issue. Please put e.printStackTrace() and post your logcat error trace.

Comment: done. It says that there are a NullObjectRefernce somewhere=/

Comment: What is line# 755 in `ShowActivity.java`??

Comment: It is StartAct method as you suggested to do it. '    `public void startAct(boolean Swiped)
    {
        if(Swiped) {
            System.out.println("I'm here!");
            mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You have confused the flow of your program. Setting a listener does not pause the program, and ending an in-listener method does not return to the method that created the listener. When you set a listener, you **only set the listener**, without running it. And then your program moves on.

This is what your program is dong:

1. It sets the SwipeListener for webView.
2. It asks `if (Swiped == true)`. But Swiped is false because listener is never automatically called upon setting, so activity is not started.
3. It moves on.

And when a swipe happens, your program **runs only what was defined in the listener**. `mContext.startActivity(myIntent);` doesn't exist either in `onSwipeLeft()` or in `onSwipeRight()` methods. They just `putExtra`, then `println`, and then set `Swipe` to true. And then it moves on with user interface which has just called one of your `onSwipe` methods. You must insert `mContext.startActivity(myIntent);` in both of your listener methods.

You should change your code to this:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeListener(this)
{
    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft()
    {
        articleID--;
        //System.out.println("SWIPE_LEFT");
        myIntent.putExtra("id", articleID);
        System.out.println(myIntent.toString());
        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight()
    {
        articleID++;
        //System.out.println("SWIPE_RIGHT");
        myIntent.putExtra("id", articleID);
        System.out.println(myIntent.toString());
        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

On the new problem, it seems like your myIntent turns out to be null somehow. It might be because of code-changing during attempts to fix it. Anyway, this update will probably not fail you. Make sure you do exactly as I describe.

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeListener(this)
{
    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft()
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext.getBaseContext(), ShowActivity.class);
        articleID--;
        myIntent.putExtra("id", articleID);
        System.out.println(myIntent.toString());
        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight()
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext.getBaseContext(), ShowActivity.class);
        articleID++;
        myIntent.putExtra("id", articleID);
        System.out.println(myIntent.toString());
        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: @cruelcore1 thx for the help, but ur solution doesn't work=/ If i do as you say, it throws an exception from SwipeListener class. And according to logs it says that the problem is with some nullpointerobject reference

Comment: Your user name suits you then!  :D

Comment: @Rishka Please provide a code update on your post. By the log, myIntent happens to be null somehow.